# English Bachelor of Computer Science - Germany

Tags: computer-science, europe, germany, bachelor

I've googled so much for English Bachelor of Computer Science in Germany and I just found Jacobs University which teaches Computer Science in English. Though Germany is a place I would like to study, I am open minded for other places.

I checked Bachelor's portal, and setting Germany as a country and English as language, it gives me a full list of universities, but unfortunately when visiting the course site it's always set as taught language: German or 50% German and 50% English.

Other than Bachelor's Portal, is there anywhere else I could search for? Any good links I could be making use of?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Unfortunately "shopping questions" that request recommendations for particular programs, are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @jakebeal, ah, didn't know that. My bad, not even asking for universities that teaches in English?

Comment: Maybe you can revise your question to ask about _resources_ to find English-language academic programs in Germany, or continental Europe.  (Note this site also is for graduate level and above, so you should also make your question applicable to say Master's programs.)

Comment: @Kimball, better?

Comment: I don't think there are many CS Bachelors taught in English in Germany. At my current university a basic knowledge of English was a requirement for the Master but they have changed it and now it's just a recommendation. Even though English is very important throughout your study I guess they have problems to make it a requirement here.

Comment: @flo I guess offering an international bachelor degree is not worth the effort for most German universities. And if it is not an international degree, students need to be able to complete all necessary requirements in the national language, meaning all required courses must be offered in German anyways.

Comment: @silvado: "if it is not an international degree, students need to be able to complete all necessary requirements in the national language, meaning all required courses must be offered in German anyways" - are you sure about this? It is true that courses are often not provided in English unless it is absolutely necessary because some material is already available in German and it is seen as too cumbersome to translate everything. However, students at German universities (at least as far as I've seen in CS) are routinely required to understand English, e.g. when parts of the material are ...

Comment: ... already available in English only, or if members of the teaching staff do not speak German. Also, quite some lectures are taught in a mode where slides are always in English, and the professor will speak German unless any of the students present points out they do not understand German, at which moment the professor will switch to English, too. As far as I know, none of these observations were related to anything specifically called "international degree".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper For Bachelor obligatory courses, I haven't observed this, but I can imagine that it may be done informally in some places. However, doing it "officially" is a different story and would mean to designate the study program as English language program.

Comment: @silvado: I still somehow doubt that, and there are countless examples of lecture descriptions on websites of German universities (including descriptions in "Modulhandbüchern", which is as official as it can possibly get, such as [this](http://www.informatik.uni-heidelberg.de/fileadmin/pdf/WS2010/2010-06-14-BSC-Modulhandbuch.pdf), or [this](https://www.uni-weimar.de/qisserver/rds;jsessionid=AF52D71A35C82832D7B81393385CA847?state=verpublish&publishContainer=lectureContainer&publishid=28586)) that explicitly state some classes are given in English, some in German, and some ...

Comment: ... in a mixture of both (lectures in English, accompanying assignments and problems in German, etc.). Granted, it is possible these are not *required* courses (that is, without any alternative), although it completely escapes me how, for instance, certain basic CS courses could possibly be offered under the assumption that only knowing German would suffice, when evidently various required assignments within these courses cannot be solved by students who are unable to read e.g. the certain software documentation or certain research papers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out the [Hochschulkompass](http://www.hochschulkompass.de/en/degree-programmes/search/) (Higher Education Compass) of the Hochschulrektorenkonferenz (German Rectors' Conference).

Searching for international programs granted with a Bachelor degree in Informatik (computer science is mostly called that in Germany) ends with 13 results. Maybe you can find a fitting study program for you there.

Comment: This is a good database, but not often kept up-to-date by the program coordinators. There is currently a push to offer more courses and even programs in English, but communication with the outside world is not the strength of many CS departments (called something with "Informatik" ususally). There has to be some pain for the free tuition: you need to learn German.

Comment: Debora Weber-Wulff. This is not only a weakness of the CS departments. It's of less priority to keep portals like this up to date for the universities as long as they offer 1 place to study to 10+ applicants. :-)